# Google Map not displaying - localhost

Tags: google-maps, localhost

This exact code has worked on previous projects, however it is not working now.

The map does not display, however I see the JS show in chrome inspect tools. The div element for the map is there etc, just no visible map. I am using AFC, and have triple checked spelling etc.

Code below:

```
<!--place google map here-->
                <div id="view1">
                    <?php
                        $location = get_field('store_location');

                        if( ! empty($location) ):
                        ?>
                            <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;"></div>
                            <script src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false' type='text/javascript'></script>

                            <script type="text/javascript">
                              //<![CDATA[
                                function load() {
                                var lat = <?php echo $location['lat']; ?>;
                                var lng = <?php echo $location['lng']; ?>;
                            // coordinates to latLng
                                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                            // map Options
                                var myOptions = {
                                zoom: 9,
                                center: latlng,
                                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                               };
                            //draw a map
                                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: map.getCenter(),
                                map: map
                               });
                            }
                            // call the function
                               load();
                            //]]>
                            </script>
                    <?php endif; ?> 

                </div>
```

See any problems?

Comment: The posted code works for me (when I provide the missing information, i.e. location).  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue (shouldn't require any PHP...)

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

Issue had to do with flexbox and bootstrap. Was using flexbox for equal column height throught site, but that seems to break this AFC google map. Placed the map outside the bootstrap column and issue was resolved.